# Special Symfony2 cache file permission issue on Mac

Tags: macos, apache, symfony, file-permissions

I already read the multiple questions regarding symfony and permission issues.

My problem is this:
When cache:clear creates the directory, apache can't access the cache.
When apache creates the directory on page call, cache:clear can't access.

The fun thing is that it only occurs in one project (which I got from a customer).
In all others it works from both sides. So something with the permissions seems to be wrong.

For a start, I delete all folders within app/cache.
Then I set a `sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache`.

We should have a clean start now.

**Test 1**

Now I run app/dev cache:clear. Folders dev and prod will be created.
I take a look at the permissions on the dev folder:

`crismancich (me) - Custom
_www - Custom
crismancich (me) - Read & Write
wheel - Read only
everyone - Read only`

As a result apache will not be able to write in the cache.

**Test 2**

Now I try the other direction. Again I delete the subfolders via `sudo rm -r app/cache/*` and set a `sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache`.

Then I just call the website via my browser. The dev directory is created. The permissions are as follows:

`crismancich (me) - Custom
_www - Custom
_www - Read & Write
wheel - Read only
everyone - read only`

Now apache can access the files. But when I use `app/console cache:clear`, I get a...

`[RuntimeException]                         Publication
  Unable to write in the cache directory (/Workspace/ACME_Compliance_Tool_HE
  AD/ComplianceTool/app/cache/dev)

**Additional Tests**

When I go on from here andf fire the recursive chmod again, the `app/console cache:clear` at least starts but bumps into an error deeper down...

`[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]

  Failed to remove file /Workspace/ACME_Compliance_Tool_HEAD/ComplianceTool/

  app/cache/dev_old/profiler/81/27/ba2781`

In fact there is no `app/cache/dev_old`. I guess the cache:clear would first rename and then delete the directory. Looks like the renaming does not work and this error is not handled.

If I use `sudo app/console cache:clear`, it will work, But then again apache can't access the files and will leave me with a blank page and the error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Failed to write cache file "/Workspace/ACME_Compliance_Tool_HEAD/ComplianceTool/app/cache/dev/classes.php".' in /Workspace/ACME_Compliance_Tool_HEAD/ComplianceTool/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php:205`

Using the file info dialog in finder and granting Read & Write for _www for cache or dev and all subfolders or the whole folder structure from "/Workspace/ACME_Compliance_Tool_HEAD" has no effect at all.

A `sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache` lets apache create cache files again, but then again, cache:clear can't delete the files created by apache.

**Result**
I end up chmodding each time I have to use console commands that create/change/delete files. By the time that's very annoying.

**My question**
Why does it work with different projects? Where is the problem?

Comment: It's normal, when you create file, file belong to you right? Read how to setup permissions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions

Comment: Hi Malcolm and thanks for the reply. I should have mentioned I followed this article carefully and tried out every single option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find the reason, but I found a solution:

I zipped the files and unzipped them to a new directory. That way I seem to have gotten rid of the permission problem whatever it was.

Comment: Interestingly it works only when it is unzipped to a new unused directory. When I delete the old one, unzip it to the same location, I seem to 'inherit' the same problem again. I guess not from the parent directory, als this is /Workspace in my case and other projects in Workspace never had the issue. Just this project I got from a customer.

Comment: That is somehow brilliant :)